# SQL, left join table, How to keep only one value?

Tags: sql, left-join

I would like to join two tables.
The table 1 is like this:

```
id      Date
a     01.01.2021
a     02.01.2021
a     03.01.2021
b     01.01.2021
b     02.01.2021
b     03.01.2021
c     01.01.2021
c     02.01.2021
c     03.01.2021
```

The table 2 is like this:

```
id  value 
a    12
a     8
b    50
```

As final result, I would like to have a table like this:
for an existing id from table 2, the sum of the value of the same id should be stored in the last date in the table 1.

```
   id       Date     Value_FINAL
   a     01.01.2021    0
   a     02.01.2021    0
   a     03.01.2021    20
   b     01.01.2021    0
   b     02.01.2021    0
   b     03.01.2021    50
   c     01.01.2021    0
   c     02.01.2021    0
   c     03.01.2021    0
```

I tried to use left join to join these two tables at first,

```
with t3 as ( select id, sum(value) Value_FINAL from t2 group by id) 
            select t1.*, t3.value_FINAL from t1 left join t3 on t1.id = t3.id;
```

After this, I can get this:

```
   id       Date     Value_FINAL
   a     01.01.2021    20
   a     02.01.2021    20
   a     03.01.2021    20
   b     01.01.2021    50
   b     02.01.2021    50
   b     03.01.2021    50
   c     01.01.2021    0
   c     02.01.2021    0
   c     03.01.2021    0
```

But, it is not I want. can someone help with this? How can I keep the value only in the last Date in the column 'value_FINAL'
I am also thinking about to use `last_value(value) over (partition by id order by date)`. But I need to create an extra table or column.
maybe someone has a good idea how to deal this problem?

Comment: Which database system?

Comment: @ Erwin Brandstetter Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`.  One method is:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) = 1
             then (select coalesce(sum(t2.value), 0) from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
             else 0
        end) as value_final
from table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 3):

A `join` based alternative

```
 select a.*, coalesce(c.value,0)
 from t1 a
 left join (select id, max(date) date from t1 group by id) b on a.id = b.id and a.date = b.date
 left join (select id, sum(value) value  from t2 group by id) c on b.id = c.id
```

Comment: perfect solution for my MSSQL requirement. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to identify the row where you want to place the total value.

For example:

```
select
  t1.id, t1.date, b.total,
  case when
    row_number() over(partition by t1.id order by t1.date desc) = 1
  then b.total
  else 0 end as value_final
from t1
left join (select id, sum(value) as total from t2 group by id) b 
  on b.id = t1.id
```